# How to fix tilde issue in git bash?

Tags: git-bash

The following tests show that tilde does not work. Is there way to fix?

```
MINGW64 ~/work
$ if test -d 'bin' ; then echo "yes" ; fi
yes

MINGW64 ~/work
$ if [ -d 'bin' ] ; then echo "yes" ; fi
yes

MINGW64 ~/work
$ if [ -d '~/work/bin' ] ; then echo "yes" ; fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding quotes:

- `'~/...'` would make that a string literal (so `~` would *not* be expanded), and `~/...` (with the actual `~`) does not exist as a path.
- `"~/..."` does not work either: [`~` is not expanded either inside double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151865/7490).

Use `${HOME}` instead, with double-quotes to ensure the environment variable expansion:

```bash
$ if [ -d "${HOME}/work/bin" ] ; then echo "yes" ; fi
yes
```